# Factorial calculation using array

Tags: arrays, c, numbers, factorial, digits

I have a program that calculates the factorial of a number (even over 20), but views the number as a series of digits. In this way:
[image]
Here's code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXCIF 1000
int main()
{
  int f[MAXCIF] = { 1 };
  int i, j, n, pom, transmission;
do
{
 printf("n="); scanf("%d", &n);
} while (n < 1 || n > 100);
for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0,transmission=0; j < MAXCIF; j++)
    {
        pom = f[j] * i + transmission;
        f[j] = pom % 10;
        transmission = pom / 10;
    }
}
printf("%d != ", n);
for (j = MAXCIF - 1; f[j] == 0; j--); // It will skip leading zeros
for (; j >= 0; j--)
printf("%d", f[j]); // Prints digits
return 0;
}
```

What makes me a problem is that I don't understand how these two loops work

```
for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
{
    for (j = 0,transmission=0; j < MAXCIF; j++)
    {
        pom = f[j] * i + transmission;
        f[j] = pom % 10;
        transmission = pom / 10;
    }
}
```

For example, take n = 2:

As I understand these loops, `pom = 2`, `f[0] = 2`, `transmission = 0`.
In the next iteration `j = 1`, then how is `f[1] = 0`?

If someone could explain these two for loops, that is, how to manually understand what is happening in them, I would be grateful.

Comment: You do not understand how the code you have written works? Why do you think we on Stack Overflow are better position than you to understand your code?

Comment: I didn't write the code

Comment: I don't understand your code because I have difficulties reading it because it it poorly indented. Indent your code properly and then maybe someone is willing to help you, and maybe __you__ will even understand it yourself.

Comment: Ok, if you didn't write it, why don't you ask the code owner (I assume you didn't steal someone else's code)? Again, this seems a more fruitful exercise.

Comment: @SergeyA Give the guy a break, I'm guessing he found this in a public code repository and he's trying to understand how it works.

Comment: I suggest you step through the program in a debugger. Or write the variables down on paper and execute the algorithm by hand. This is how I've been doing it for decades when I don't understand some complicated code.

Comment: I got this code at school in one exercise, they didn't explain it very well, or I didn't understand, so I'm asking here for help

Comment: The initialization of `f` sets `f[0] = 1` and all the rest of the elements to `0`.

Comment: Why is this so, where the array is reset, that is, why is only the first member one?

Comment: When you specify any initializers for an array, all the others default to 0.

Comment: So `int f[MAXCIF] = { 1 };` is equivalent to `int f[MAXCIF] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, ... };` where there are `MAXCIF - 1` zeroes.

Comment: The loop you're asking about is doing multiplication, "by hand", one digit at a time, sort of the way you learned how to do paper-and-pencil multiplication in elementary school.  For each digit in the `f` array, from right to left, it multiplies that digit by `i`.  This multiplicitation will often overflow to more than one digit, so there may be a carry to the next digit.  The carry takes place via the variable named `transmission`.  At any rate, it does the multiplication for `i` running from 2 to `n`, thus computing the factorial of `n`.

Comment: This is a small, concise, and actually rather nice implementation of [*multiprecision arithmetic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic).

Comment: @Barmar Thank you so much, you really helped me !